# Add an Icon to NbSelect

Tags: angular, typescript, nebular

I am using Nebular for a project and there are very many dropdowns which are used as follows:

```
<nb-select fullWidth placeholder="Office" formControlName="office">
  <nb-option value="Office_A">Office A</nb-option>
</nb-select>
```

This will look like this:

[image: Dropdown image]

I want to add a close (x) icon to this drop down next to the down chevron to look like the following:

[image: requirement]

And I want to add an onClick event to that icon.

Is there any way to do this?

Edit: I'm not necessarily looking for a method from Nebular itself. Even a workaround would do.

Comment: This is not supported by default by ng-select.

Comment: @GRD Thanks for letting me know that. Is there a workaround? Someway to even overlay the icon? I did try, but have been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional icon to the select via the nb-form-field component

```
 <nb-form-field>
      <nb-icon nbSuffix icon="alert-circle-outline"></nb-icon>
      <nb-select placeholder="Select Showcase">
        <nb-option>Reset</nb-option>
        <nb-option value="1">Option 1</nb-option>
        <nb-option value="2">Option 2</nb-option>
        <nb-option value="3">Option 3</nb-option>
      </nb-select>
  </nb-form-field>
```

Comment: Do you have a working example because I tried and it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you share stackblitz?